# create columns based on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains column names as below

Dataset1:

```
df1_columns = [adult    adultold    old old1    old2    old3    old4    old6]

In dataframe2 i have columns subset of column 1, now I want to add columns which I have in dataframe 1.
```

Dataframe2:

```
adult   adultold    old2    old5
0   0   1   0
1   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
```

I want to do something like this based on the column names of dataframe1 and add the same column names to dataset 2 with zeros.

```
dataframe1.columns = [adult,    adultold,   old,    old1,   old2,   old3,   old4,   old6]

dataframe2.columns = [adult,    adultold,   old2    old5]

if x in dataframe1.columns:
     if y in dataframe2.columns:
           pass
     else:
           dataframe2['y'] = (fill with zeros)
```

output :

```
adult   adultold    old old1    old2    old3    old4    old6
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Can we get the new dataframe in the order as in df1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) if inputs are lists of columns names for `Series` and for new columns names [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
s = pd.Series(0, index=np.setdiff1d(dataframe1_columns, dataframe2_columns))
print (s)
old2    0
old3    0
old4    0
old6    0
dtype: int64

df = dataframe2.assign(**s)
print (df)
    adult  adultold  old  old1  old2  old3  old4  old6
0       0         0    1     0     0     0     0     0
1       1         0    0     0     0     0     0     0
2       1         0    0     0     0     0     0     0
3       0         0    0     0     0     0     0     0
4       1         0    0     0     0     0     0     0
5       1         0    0     0     0     0     0     0
6       0         0    0     1     0     0     0     0
7       0         0    0     0     0     0     0     0
8       0         0    0     0     0     0     0     0
9       0         0    0     0     0     0     0     0
10      0         0    0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: what if i only know the column names but not the dataframe, `dataframe1_columns = [adult,    adultold,   old,    old1,   old2,   old3,   old4,   old6]`

Comment: @jezrael please explain. This is an amazing one-liner!

Comment: sure, give me a sec.

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan , jezrael is an amazing coder for me. Lots to learn from him. Thanks Jez.

Comment: @pylearner haha agreed I usually try not to come on his way when he is blitzing it :-)

Comment: what if I want to make them in the same order as df1 ?

Comment: Then add `dataframe2.assign(**s).reindex(columns=dataframe1_columns)`

Comment: Awesome, I got it. Thanks a ton Jez!

Answer (score 1):

Use -

```
list_of_cols_not_in_df2 = df.columns.difference(df2.columns) # @jez thanks for teaching difference
pd.concat([df2, pd.DataFrame(0, df2.index, list_of_cols_not_in_df2 )], axis=1)
```

***using join instead of concat***

```
df2.join(pd.DataFrame(0, df2.index, list_of_cols_not_in_df2 ))
```

**Output**

```
    adult   adultold    old old1    old2    old3    old4    old6
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: what if i only know the column names but not the dataframe, dataframe1_columns = [adult, adultold, old, old1, old2, old3, old4, old6]

Comment: @pylearner according to the updated qstn, both jezrael and I have put down what you need. How are these solutions different from what you want?

Comment: I dont have a dataframe1 at all... I have a list of names in my case. So jezz has did it.